# Composing references to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type

Tags: lambda, compiler-errors, java-8, method-reference

This compiles with no errors:

```
Function<T, List<R>> f = T::getRs;
Function<List<R>, Stream<R>> g = List::stream;
Function<T, Stream<R>> h = f.andThen(g);
List<T> ts = ...;
ts.stream().flatMap(h);
```

But this produces errors:

```
List<T> ts = ...;
ts.stream().flatMap(T::getRs.andThen(List::stream));
```

The errors are:

```
error: method reference not expected here
        .flatMap(T::getRs.andThen((List::stream)))
                 ^
error: invalid method reference
        .flatMap(T::getRs.andThen((List::stream)))
                                   ^
  non-static method stream() cannot be referenced from a static context
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface Collection
```

I would have thought that the two approaches would be equivalent.  Am I missing some syntax?  Some grouping somewhere perhaps?  I would prefer to take the latter "one-line" approach if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the correct syntax for a method reference; it seems as if you're trying to call something like this (note the parentheses, even though it's still incorrect):

```
List<T> ts = ...;

ts.stream().flatMap((T::getRs).andThen(List::stream));
```

To have it on one line, you can split it up into a call to `Stream#map` and then `Stream#flatMap`:

```
List<T> ts = ...;

ts.stream().map(T::getRs).flatMap(List::stream);
```

Comment: As in how you do it in your example, or mine?

Comment: In my example please.

Comment: Your first example compiles because it's just a sequential stream of `Function`s.

Comment: Do you mean that a method reference cannot be de-referenced using the `.` operator?

Comment: Yes, hence why the mappings must be separate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your one-line solution is, the compiler needs a target type to call `andThen`. If you cast your first method reference to a `Function` it is working just fine:

```
ts.stream().flatMap(((Function<T, List<R>>) T::getRs).andThen(List::stream));
```

The preferred way is to split this two into a `map` and `flatMap` or use a lambda expression, since it is more readable.

Comment: or `.flatMap(t -> t.getRs().stream())`…